# Group By then concat items with commas

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Using event hubs, I'm pushing my data to azure stream analytics. SearchWords, ItemId, UserId are some my data property.

What I want to do is, grouping my searchwords and concat the items. For example:

```
Data:
    SearchWords ItemId UserID
    wordA - 100 - 1
    wordA - 102 - 1
    wordC - 103 - 2
    wordD - 102 - 3
    wordA - 105 - 5

    Output:
    wordA - 100,102,105
    wordC - 103
    wordD - 102
```

How can i do this in stream analytics query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use user defined aggregates to do this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-aggregates